# Performance Improvement with Entity Framework 6 compiled queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

From the [Compiled Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx) documentation:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, LINQ queries are cached automatically. However, you can still use compiled LINQ queries to reduce this cost in later executions and compiled queries can be more efficient than LINQ queries that are automatically cached. Note that LINQ to Entities queries that apply the Enumerable.Contains operator to in-memory collections are not automatically cached. Also parameterizing in-memory collections in compiled LINQ queries is not allowed.

So does it mean that LINQ queries in Entity Framework 6.x still need to translate to actual SQL commands on the fly? and can be improved with The [`CompiledQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.compiledquery%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class?

Thanks